# Compiletime resolving of member pointer passed as function argument

Tags: c++

I would like to allow the compiler to do as many optimizations at compile-time as possible. So, as far as I know, passing the member pointer as a template argument like in the following code block would be the best way:

```
struct obj {
   double x;
};

template <auto member, typename T>
void test1(T* obj) {
    obj->*member = 10.;
}

auto main() -> int {
   auto o = obj();

   test1<&obj::x>(&o);

   return 0;
}
```

But the `test<&obj::x>(&o)` construct has one problem that I cant create my API in a consistent way, because there are situations in which I would like to allow to pass runtime dependent arguments to the `test` function, instead of the using `&obj::x` as a template argument. So the other way to solve that is:

```
struct obj {
   double x;
};

template <typename T, typename MemberType>
void test2(T* obj, MemberType T::*const& member) {
    obj->*member = 10.;
}

auto main() -> int {
   auto o = obj();

   test2(&o, &obj::x);

   return 0;
}
```

But now `&obj::x` is a runtime dependent value. Is there a way that allows me to call `test1` from `test2` in case that the argument passed to `test2` is already known at compile-time?

I know that this is possible with `constexpr` variables:

```
struct obj {
   double x;
};

template <auto member, typename T>
void test1(T* obj) {
    obj->*member = 10.;
}

auto main() -> int {
   auto o = obj();

   constexpr double obj::*member = &obj::x;
   test1<member>(&o);

   return 0;
}
```

But is there a way to do this for a function parameter?

I can't make any assumptions about the object passed to the function nor about the type of the member variable.

**Background information:**

I want to create a general-purpose timeline function, that allows to interpolate the values of member variables. And to invoke callback function at certain keyframes.

```
timeline t;

t.add_keyframe<&obj::x>(0, &o, 10. /* easing function */);
t.add_keyframe<&obj::x>(10, &o, 20. /* easing function */);
t.add_keyframe(10, [](time_t t) {
   // do something
});
```

It is not a big deal that I have `t.add_keyframe<&obj::x>(…)` and  `t.add_keyframe(`, I was just wondering if `t.add_keyframe(10, &o, &obj::x, … );` is somehow possible but with compile-time resolving of the member pointer.

Comment: The first idea that come to mind would be to wrap `test1` / `test2` in a class and provide specializations ? But that being said, you would end up with a lot of them, but tehnically that would solve it.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I guess that won't work. I want to create a timeline class that allows to add keyframes for arbitrary objects. something like `t.add_keyframe<&obj::x>(0, &o, 1.)` and the compiled code looks fine regarding optimizations. But I also want to allow that certain functions (e.g. lambda functions) are called, so the signature would idally be `t.add_keyframe(0, &o, &obj::x, 1.);` and `t.add_keyframe(0, [](time_t time) {});`. But then the compiler misses some optimizations that for `t.add_keyframe(0, &o, &obj::x, 1.);`, not a big deal, but still a bit annoying.

Comment: I mean having `t.add_keyframe<&obj::x>(0, &o, 1.)` and `t.add_keyframe(0, [](time_t time) {});` is not necessarily bad, I was just wondering if `t.add_keyframe(0, &o, &obj::x, 1.);` can be done in a way that the compiler can do the same optimizations as it can do for `t.add_keyframe<&obj::x>(0, &o, 1.)`

Comment: well it could be done, but there are some underlaying assumptions that I don't know if you'd be happy with. Ideally, if you can declare unique types for the parameters you know with using, then you could achieve that, but what is someone messes and passes a different variable with the same type. I'll try to make a sample, so that what I am proposing makes more sense.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis before you start, the member pointer could be a pointer to any type. I can't know that type before.

Comment: But that applies only to the runtime invocation case? Or even in the compile time scenario, you don't control the type `T` and `T` could be anything? If so then yeah, my approach will not work:)

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis it should be a header-only library that could be used by anyone, so I don't know what `obj` will be nor what the member will be. And I don't want to enforce any inheritance from a type that I defined.

Comment: ok, yeah then specialisations are not an option since the anyone would need to add using directives and specialisations for their types, ok thanks for the clarification.